# How to fetch part of JSON array using PHP to handle large data size?

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I fetch part of a large JSON array using PHP?

my JSON array contains more than 100,000 records and can't load all data once time

I need to divide the JSON array into a set of data in order to get the data as a PHP pagination method, each page fetches a set of data ( e.x. page number 1 fetch from array 1 to 100, page number 2 fetch from array 101 to array 200, and so and ).

PHP Code

```
<?php
//....
$data = file_get_contents("data.json");
//var_dump($JsonParser);
$json_output = json_decode($data, TRUE);
echo json_encode($json_output);
//....
?>
```

JSON array

```
{
  "current": 1,
  "rowCount": 100,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T20:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id":4 ,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "sender": "123@test.de",
      "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00"
    },
...
  ],
  "total": 1001023
}
```

Comment: You could try a streaming JSON parser like: https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser

Comment: Do you think perhaps that at this scale, JSON is not a good persistence mechanism?